# How to fix DPDK error 'MBUF: error setting mempool handler'

Tags: dpdk

I am using some DPDK application code that worked with DPDK 2.2.0.  I am trying to port it to DPDK 18.08, running on Centos 7.  The code gives error:

```
MBUF: error setting mempool handler
```

This error occurs in the call to rte_pktmbuf_pool_create() below:

```
    for (lcore_id = 0; lcore_id < RTE_MAX_LCORE; lcore_id++) {

        if (rte_lcore_is_enabled(lcore_id) == 0)
            continue;

        iCpuSocket = rte_lcore_to_socket_id(lcore_id);

        if (iCpuSocket == SOCKET_ID_ANY)
            iCpuSocket = 0;

        // Preparing direct memory pool per Socket

        if (socket_direct_pool[iCpuSocket] == NULL) 
        {
            mp = rte_pktmbuf_pool_create(   buf,
                                            NB_MBUF,
                                            32,
                                            0,
                                            RTE_MBUF_DEFAULT_BUF_SIZE,
                                            iCpuSocket); 
            if (mp == NULL) {
                <print error>
                return -1;
            }
            socket_direct_pool[iCpuSocket] = mp;
        }
```

I don't know how to fix this. I have seen other people reporting this when building the dpdk application code as a library (i.e. there were missing symbols), but I am building directly as an executable.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: does standalone `rte_pktmbuf_pool_create` work? that is, ignore the for loop?

Comment: rte_pktmbuf_pool_create() fails on the first iteration of the for loop, i.e. even if it is only called once.

Comment: as suspected, looks like parameter error can you do the following. 1) run with `--log-level=eal,8` 2)  print the error value 3) print rte_strerror(rte_errno)

Comment: With --log-level=eal,8 I see:

"EAL: Module /sys/module/vfio not found! error 2 (No such file or directory)"

Was there another error value that you wanted me to print?

Comment: can you replace your ` <print error>` with `printf(" failed to create mempool, ret (%s) ~~\n". rte_strerror(rte_errno));`

Comment: "Failed to create mempool, ret (Invalid argument) ~~"

Comment: My arguments are:
rte_pktmbuf_pool_create("pool_direct_0", 8192, 32, 0, 2176, 0)

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the error with same value in DPDK `dpdk-stable-18.11.7`. Can you run `example/l2fwd`

Comment: Thanks for your replies. This appears to work:
build/l2fwd -c 1 -n 4 -- -p 0x1
I'll try my own app with 18.11.7 instead of 18.08

Comment: ok will wait for your updates

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215574/discussion-between-davida-and-vipin-varghese).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments and chat interaction, the problem is root caused as `have aligned the library link order of my app with that of l2fwd and the rte_pktmbuf_pool_create() error is fixed. Thanks for pointing me to l2fwd and for bearing with me.`

that is, the problem appears to solved by

1. linking with the RTE_SDK & RTE_TARGET
2. modifying the application to use the semantics similar to example/l2fwd

for VFIO not found warning, it can be ignored since the driver in use is igb_uio and not VFIO-PCI for the physical interface.